# Pulling a table from a SQL Server database into a List<> in C# using Entity Framework

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm a programmer who just began working in a Windows environment and i'm new to web development and have poor previous database experience. Currently at my internship I was asked to pull the information from a large SQL Server database and store it into a list and make a website to display the information. Being new to most of these concepts, I've been reading up on MVC, Linq, and EF since that is what they primarily use.

I am trying to figure out how to pull the table into a list, but so far the internet hasn't been much help. Most solutions are for a database you create in the project or they use the CodeFirst method. The solution i'm working on in Visual Studio (2012) is MASSIVE and the database is already included in the project.

From what I gathered, I should make a class for the table and make an object for each column and then store that class in a List<>. The part of querying the database and storing all the elements is what eludes me. I've been reading for a few days, but keep having trouble grasping exactly how to do it. Should I be using interfaces? (Also, I searched to the source code and they don't really use DbConnect or anything... half the reason i'm confused.)

Sorry that I have to real code to show, but I would appreciate any insight! I can clarify anything you'd like. Thanks!

Comment: have a look to these links:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/data/jj573936, http://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/bb399572.aspx

Comment: If there is existing code, I would look through it for the pattern that is currently being used, and follow that pattern.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
List<YourTable> list;
using (YourDataBaseEntities context = new YourDataBaseEntities())
{
    list = context.YourTables.toList();
}
```

Will get you every object from the table you specified in your database. YourTable will be the object associated with that table and YourDataBaseEntities will be the object for your database as generated by the Entity Framework model that you have.

Comment: This is what I was doing initially, but the tough part was sifting through all the files to find the right one to use to connect to the database.

Answer (score 0):

After you create your EDMX, Entity framework will create a class for each table you have on your database.

and you can access the information like this using lambda expressions:

```
List<TableName> Content = context.TableName.Select(x=> x).ToList<TableName>();
```

Comment: I don't think it's LINQ that will create the classes. Entity Framework will create the classes which can be queried via LINQ.